# Compare variable against multiple columns of different data types?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to lookup a search term passed into `@Search` in both an `INT` column and  a `NVARCHAR` column.

I have done searching multiple columns in the past similar to below but have never had to compare against different column types.

```
@Search NVARCHAR(1000)

SELECT
  [Stuff]
FROM 
  [Tables]
WHERE
  [IDColumn] = ISNULL(@Search, [IDColumn])
OR
  [TextColumn] LIKE '%' + TRIM(@Search) + '%'
```

How can the passed in variable be checked against multiple columns of different data types?

Comment: This is asking for trouble on multiple levels. Text isn't a number, so comparing a numeric column with a string will cause the text to be parsed based on the database's collation . This may not cause problems with integers, but can result in parsing issues with decimals and dates. The catch-all `ISNULL(@Search, [IDColumn])` can result in bad execution plans too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is the `OR` part of the statement that I am adding to the existing where clause here which has not been refactored yet. The catch all was used to return a full set of records when no `@Search INT` parameter was passed. In practice I would first return an int as 0 and set it to NULL in sql prior to the catchall. Would this still cause concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the values.  If it is a character, I would suggest `try_convert()`:

```
WHERE IDColumn = TRY_CONVERT(INT, @Search) OR
      TextColumn LIKE CONCAT('%', TRIM(@Search), '%')
```

Comment: Thanks, I had been using TRY_PARSE unsuccessfully.